# Centos 7 - Locked out of accessing the VPS after enforcing SELinux

Tags: ssh, centos7

As title says, I can't log into my VPS after enforcing the Sellinux flag.
Do I have any options to get in without reinstalling the OS and losing all my configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Does your VPS provider allow you to use a live CD or rescue image?  With some VPS providers, there's a Solus VM control panel where you can boot into Rescue with the kernel version you need.

Once you can boot in, you can access your main volume and perform whatever semanage commands needed.

```
# chroot /mnt/sysimage
```

[Screenshot of SolusVM control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGcSW.png)